# Recent Folder directory location in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, directory

What is the location of Recent in the directory structure, which can be seen on the left panel of the window explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is located in your personal user directory, and stored in the following file:

```
~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```